# 2 react select - I want to set the value of one select box based on change on the 2nd select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a component that holds 2 sub components (of the same kind)

when I pick a time in the first select I want to test it and set the second select accordingly (if the time is higher than the 2nd or the 2nd doesn't have a value - I want to set it to 1 hour later).

My problem is that although the setEndTime is being called - the acual value in the select box doesn't change. what am I missing ? (the first select gets the new value and shows it,  the second select only shows value if I change it myself).

the sub component has a react-select element (to keep this short - I omitted some of the code) the options is an array of elements that has date value and lable.

```
    const MyTimePicker = (props) => {
    const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(null);
   
  const changeSelectedTime = (value) => {   
    props.onTimeChanged(value);
    setCurrentValue(value.value);
  }
  console.log('current day: ' + props.CurrentDay)

    let timeArray = timeSlotArray.map(x => {return {value: x, label: x.getHours() + ':' + (x.getMinutes()<10 ? '0':'') + x.getMinutes()}});

    return (
    <div>
        <Select className={classes.selectBox} options={timeArray} onChange={changeSelectedTime} value={timeArray.filter((o)=>{return ( currentValue ?  currentValue.getTime() === o.value.getTime() : false)})}></Select>
    </div>
        );
}
export default MyTimePicker;
```

The father component that uses this looks like this:

```
import MyTimePicker from '../UI/MyTimePicker';

const AddSchedule = (props) => {
  
    const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(props.ClickedStartTime);
    const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState(props.ClickedStartTime);
     
    const onStartTimeChange = (newTime) => {
      
        setStartTime(newTime.value);
      
        if(newTime.value >= endTime || !endTime)
        {
            let newned = new Date(newTime.value.getTime());
            setEndTime(newned.setHours(newned.getHours() + 1));          
        }
    }

    const onEndTimeChange = (newTime) => {      
        setEndTime(newTime.value);
    }
   
    return (
        <Modal>
           
            <MyTimePicker me='start' CurrentDay={Date()} onTimeChanged={onStartTimeChange} value={startTime}></MyTimePicker>
            <MyTimePicker me='end' CurrentDay={Date()} onTimeChanged={onEndTimeChange} value={endTime}></MyTimePicker>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default AddSchedule;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(null);
```

instead of null it needs to get the time value.